# session does not support in mozilla

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
@$_SESSION['title'] = $_POST['title'];
@$_SESSION['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
@$_SESSION['add1'] = $_POST['add1'];
@$_SESSION['add2'] = $_POST['add2'];
@$_SESSION['add3'] = $_POST['add3'];
@$_SESSION['city'] = $_POST['city'];
@$_SESSION['state'] = $_POST['state'];
@$_SESSION['zip'] = $_POST['zip'];
@$_SESSION['country'] = $_POST['country'];
```

I have assign session variables but it can not supported in mozilla and internet browser. Can I run this code without session manager add one in mozila?

Comment: have you set `session_start();` before to assign the variables??

Comment: That just look so wrong. Surpressing errors and wondering why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably because you are missing `session_start();` at the beginning of the script.
Read more about [sessions here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php). Without more detail about the issue I cannot think of anything else.